# Any way to get proper C++ stack unwinding when duktape throws an error?

Tags: duktape

Is there currently any way to get duktape to properly unwind the C++ stack (calling all appropriate destructors, etc.) when an error is encountered in duktape?

I know that Lua (for example) has the capability to do this by switching from the use of longjmp to C++ exceptions when Lua is compiled by a C++ compiler, but at first glance I'm not seeing anything similar in duktape, and I'm definitely winding up with C++ destructors not getting called. If that capability doesn't exist yet in duktape, are there any plans for it? (If the longjmp destinations are set and used in a strictly LIFO fashion, I'm guessing it'd be doable. If not, then maybe not so doable...)

I've been playing with duktape a bit and so far I've been impressed...I'm mostly done with a C++ template-based metaprogramming library that lets you automatically create duktape bindings to C++ functions. This stack-unwinding thing may be a complete deal-breaker, though...don't think I can use duktape if I can't trust my C++ destructors to get called.

EDIT: actually, on further reflection, I can probably make things work without the stack unwinding, although of course everything will be significantly more complex and error-prone. It'd still be a great feature to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Duktape 1.2 there isn't yet support for replacing setjmp/longjmp (which are used for error handling inside Duktape) with a C++ exception friendly try-catch mechanism. Support for that is planned for future versions though.

Comment: Very glad to hear that's planned for future versions!

Comment: Another approach to handling errors might be to have most API calls (e.g. duk_get_prop) not actually throw an exception, but rather store an exception object somewhere and let the C code check for it and either throw it manually, leave it alone (in which case the JavaScript implementation can throw it when control returns to it from the C callback code) or dispose of it in some other fashion. (That's how JavaScriptCore handles the issue, for example.) No idea whether that's a sane change to make in duktape, though.

Answer (score 3):

As a quick update: Duktape 1.4.0 has support for using C++ exceptions for long control transfers (https://github.com/svaarala/duktape/tree/master/examples/cpp-exceptions):

- Define `DUK_OPT_CPP_EXCEPTIONS` (`DUK_USE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS` if you're editing `duk_config.h` directly) and compile using a C++ compiler.
- Automatic destructors will then work when Duktape/C functions unwind.
- You can't throw a C++ exception "through" Duktape however. If you do that Duktape will convert the C++ exception into an Ecmascript exception instead. So, while Duktape/C functions can use C++ exceptions internally those exceptions should be caught before they propagate to Duktape.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you didn't provide any code samples so my guess is that you haven't set an fatal error handler in [`duk_create_heap`](http://duktape.org/api.html#duk_create_heap) and you are currently using the un-protected code execution variants like [`duk_eval`](http://duktape.org/api.html#duk_eval). You should try using the [protected code execution](http://duktape.org/api.html#taglist-protected) function variants like [`duk_peval`](http://duktape.org/api.html#duk_peval) instead.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out what I needed to do. It was pretty awkward, though...there are no protected versions of duk_get_prop or duk_put_prop, for example, and duk_safe_call is painful to use. Eventually I wrote my own C++ function that accepted a lambda as an argument, stored a pointer to it on the duktape stack, and then used duk_safe_call to call a helper function that then grabbed the lambda back off the stack and called it. (Along with a bunch of other stack-twiddling to keep the stack in a reasonable state.) The whole thing is probably kinda slow.